# How to add tags into process for Jaeger span

Tags: python, jaeger, open-telemetry

I am using Python3.8 with opentelemetry libraries and I am able to create some basic spans. I need to add tags for the backend processor pick them. For E.G something like "hostname".

For this to happen I need to somehow add tags to the process. I am unable to figure out how to do this.

My trace looks like this

````
    "process": {
        "serviceName": "xxxxx"
    },
    "spans": [
        {```
I need something like
```{
    "process": {
        "serviceName": "xxxxx",
        "tags": [
            {
                "key": "jaeger.version",
                "vType": "STRING",
                "vStr": "Go-2.29.1"
            },
            {
                "key": "hostname",
                "vType": "STRING",
                "vStr": "xxxxxx"
````

This is how I am initializing my tracer and exporter

```
                TracerProvider(
                    resource=Resource.create({SERVICE_NAME: "xxxx","service.instance.id":"1","host.name":"xxxx"})
                    )
                )
        trace.set_attribute("hostname","018.zeus.run")

        tracer = trace.get_tracer(__name__)

        jaeger_exporter = JaegerExporter(
        agent_host_name='xxxxx',
        agent_port=6831,
        collector_endpoint='http://xxxxx:14268/api/traces?format=jaeger.thrift'
        )
```

Can someone please let me know how can I add tags to the process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is a bug with the exporter lib you are using. Ideally, thrift-exporter should translate the resource attributes to process tags as mentioned in the [spec](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-specification/blob/main/specification/trace/sdk_exporters/jaeger.md#resource). Here is the source where [`Process`](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-python/blob/73230b66c5497eef834d36dd7f15fa029316b5ce/exporter/opentelemetry-exporter-jaeger-thrift/src/opentelemetry/exporter/jaeger/thrift/__init__.py#L214) is instantiated with serviceName and it doesn't map the remaining resource attributes as tags, but jaeger-proto-grpc exporter correctly [maps](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-python/blob/73230b66c5497eef834d36dd7f15fa029316b5ce/exporter/opentelemetry-exporter-jaeger-proto-grpc/src/opentelemetry/exporter/jaeger/proto/grpc/translate/__init__.py#L246-L249) them. Please create an issue here https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-python.